# Get the keyboard button pressed during onClick and based on that run different functions

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I have 9 different functions which has to triggered by single button when onclick and keyboard numpad (1 to 9).

**Edit: Solution by Sode- v2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="b41" onclick="test_ks(event)">Shape Anchor Point</button>

 <script>


  const pressedButtons = {};

  window.onkeydown = (e) => (pressedButtons[e.which] = true);
  window.onkeyup = (e) => (pressedButtons[e.which] = false);

  function test_ks(event) {
    
    if (pressedButtons[97]) {
      alert('numpad 1');
    } else if (pressedButtons[98]) {
      alert('numpad 2');
    }
  }
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Tried this at**
https://manjunath7472.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2021-11-06.html

**Issue**
1.After clicking numberpad 1, numberpad 2 doesn't work & After clicking numpad2, numpad1 works but after that numpad 2 doesn't work.

2.After initial click on anyone, from second time, with just mouse
click(without pressing keyboard numpad) it triggers the alert.

3.After first clcik with keypress, it doesn't consider keyboard press and alert is triggered by mouse click only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind a function to onclick in the HTML tag you want to just pass the name of the function as the event parameter will be passed in by the DOM

```
<button type="button" id="b41" onclick="myFunction()">myButtonName</button>
```

but also, a button's click event won't have any keyboard data attached to it, so you may want to look into using keydown and keyup event listeners (probably on the window object) to keep track of which keys are pressed and using that information when the button is clicked

```
<button type="button" id="b41" onclick="myFunction()">myButtonName</button>
<span id="output"></span>

<script>
  const pressedButtons = {};

  const outputSpan = document.querySelector('#output');

  window.onkeydown = (e) => (pressedButtons[e.which] = true);
  window.onkeyup = (e) => (pressedButtons[e.which] = false);

  function myFunction(event) {
    console.log(pressedButtons);
    if (pressedButtons[97]) {
      outputSpan.innerHTML = 'numpad 1';
    } else if (pressedButtons[98]) {
      outputSpan.innerHTML = 'numpad 2';
    } else {
      outputSpan.innerHTML = '';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Edit: updated to change text of a span rather than use `alert()`

Comment: Trust me! am new to this html, js. Could you plz construct ur solution like in my question.

Comment: It still says undefined. Please check below answer.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer, but take note that the alert window seems to prevent the onkeyup handler from being fired, so if you actually plan on using alert inside of these functions it may not correctly set the keys that are pressed to false if you let the key up while that window is open.

Comment: I updated ur code in my question and tried the same in w3tryit. Couple of issues i mentioned. I noted the above comment as well.. What would be the solution finally.FYI, this is for my extension am writing for adobe after effects.

Comment: Yeah, the issues are being caused by `alert()`, the window that pops up blocks the execution of JS on your page so it never receives the keyup event if you release the key while the alert is up. If you switch it to use console.log (not sure if you can view that in after effects) or even change the text of another element you shouldn't run into these issues.

Comment: Thanks for explaining clearly, The new one working fine, but in after effects its not triggering anything. Instead of window do we have to put something else.

Comment: I'm not sure about the specifics of after effects, but maybe try changing `window` to `document` or even `document.body`

Comment: Actually somehow cep panels don't detect keypress othethan ctrl alt shift.. But there is scriptUI object which works thru csinterface.. I didn't check that first and I blindly concluded it don't work and I was searching for other solutions. Thanks for ur time and I learnt something from u